# Suppose that $G$ is a group containing subgroups $H$ and $K$. Show that $H\cup K=H \lor K$ if and only if $H\cap K\in \{H,K\}.$

Tags: group-theory

For the following question: (from A first course in Group theory by Bijan Davvaz)

> Suppose that $G$ is a group containing subgroups $H$ and $K$.  Show that $H\cup K=H \lor K$ if and only if $H\cap K\in \{H,K\}.$

I am not sure how to interpret this:  $H\cap K\in \{H,K\}.$  Both $H$ and $K$ are subgroups, then is $\{H,K\}$ suppose to be a set where its elements are both sets.  So $H\cap K\in \{H,K\}.$ would mean $H\cap K\subset H.$ and $H\cap K\subset K?$  I also know of the following facts:

$H \lor K=\langle H\cup K \rangle$

$H \lor K=\langle H\cup K \rangle=HK$ for both $H$ and $K$ being normal subgroups

$H\wedge K=H\cap K$

Also, what does it mean if I have an element $x\in \langle H\cup K \rangle$?  Does it mean for some $h_i \in H$ and $k_i\in K$, $x=h_i$ or $x=k_i$.  Thank you in advance

Comment: This is equivalent to proving that the union of two subgroups is a subgroup if and only if one of them contains the other. I'm sure it's a duplicate.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know how to do that question. I just don't know what the notation $H\cap K\in \{H,K\}.$ means?  As I stated, $H\cap K\$ is a set, so...

Comment: It means exactly what it says. the intersection is equal to an element of the set $\{H,K\}$, which is *exactly the same* as saying it is equal to either $H$ or to $K$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin does it mean it could equal to both or just one of them?

Comment: It can only equal both if $H=K$. Really, this isn't hard. If I tell you that $x\in \{a,b\}$, that means that $x=a$ or $x=b$. What else could it possibly mean?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok ok.  I understand the notation now. It is just I have never seen it written with sets as elements before.  Thank you for clarifying that up for me.

Comment: In set theory, everything is a set. You *have* seen it, you just didn't realize it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin kk. Thank you for reminding me. lol